# SQL Server & C# - How can I check if a varbinary(max) file i'm uploading already exists in a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am storing files in a table in SQL Server, in the following format:

FileID - int (auto increment),
FileName - VarBinary(MAX),
FileData - VarBinary(MAX).

What I would like to do is - by uploading a new FileName & FileData as parameters, return the first FileID where the FileName & File Data match, like so:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 FileID FROM Attachments WHERE FileName = @FileName AND FileData = @FileData", Program.connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", Path.GetFileName(MyFile));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = File.ReadAllBytes(MyFile);
int result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

However no matter what I do, the function simply terminates (with no exception) when it comes to actually execute the query, on the last line. What am I doing wrong?

I'd prefer not to grab the data for each file & do the comparison in C# if possible.

Comment: Have you considered some form of checksum or hash so that you can drastically reduce the number of full comparisons you need to perform, whether those be in C# or SQL?

Comment: Side note: you should not compare _contents_ of a file. Instead, calculate file hash and store it together with contents. Then when uploading, calculate hash and compare with what is stored in database. Since hash is _much_ shorter - it will be much more efficient.

Comment: "I'd prefer not to grab the data for each file & do the comparison in C# if possible." Reading and uploading the entire file to SQL Server and asking *it* to do the comparison is hardly more efficient. As the others said, employ a (good, cryptographically oriented) checksum that makes the chance of collisions small enough that you don't need to consider the possibility (include the file length to be damn near certain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others already wrote in their comments:
First, extend you table to hold 2 more columns. One for a hash of the contents and one for the filelength.
You can then hash the contents of the file when a user uploads it and get it's length. Then you query your SQL-Server to find rows which contain the same length and the same hash (and the same name, if you want the same file with a different name to be considered as a different file). 
If you get a hit, you don't transfer the file to the SQL-Server, if you don't get a hit, you create a new record.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What data type should I use for the hash column? I seem to have trouble executing when the where clause is on a varbinary column.

Comment: You could - for instance - convert your hash to base64 and store it in a varchar field, which supports equality queries.